# C++ de-referencing between pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Say I have a class Foo

```
class Foo {
}
```

I do following assignments:

```
Foo *ptrFoo=new Foo();

Foo &ref=*(ptrFoo);  //question 1
Foo afoo=*(ptrFoo); //quesion 2
```

My questions :

1) When assignming to "&ref"  what internally happens in-terms of memory?
 Is it just assigning the memory address of "ptrFoo" to "ref" ?

2) When assigning to "afoo", what happends? Does it call copy-constructor?That means memory is allocated for two Foo objects? ie,  "afoo" and previously assigned memory for "ptrFoo" ?

3) Say I have a method called "void methodBar(const Foo &instance)"
If I pass "ptrFoo" as:

methodBar( (*preFoo));

whats the significant of "const" here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1) When assignming to "&ref" what internally happens in-terms of memory? Is it just assigning the memory address of "ptrFoo" to "ref" ?

That depends on your platform, compiler, and compiler settings. Your compiler may just generate a synonym for the dereferencing. Because a reference may not be redefined there's no reason a compiler really needs to allocate any memory for the variable.

> 2) When assigning to "afoo", what happends? Does it call copy-constructor?That means memory is allocated for two Foo objects? ie, "afoo" and previously assigned memory for "ptrFoo" ?

Yes, the contents of the `Foo` stored in dynamic storage are copied (using the copy constructor) to the instance of `Foo` in automatic storage. There's no dynamic allocation going on here though; the `aFoo` instance would get created just as simply if there were no assignment. For instance, `Foo aFoo;`.

> 3) Say I have a method called "void methodBar(const Foo &instance)" If I pass "ptrFoo" as:
>   methodBar( (*preFoo));
>   whats the significant of "const" here ?

`const` in that position means that while the item is passed by reference, the method which declared that reference `const` is not allowed to modify the instance the reference references.

Answer (score 4):

1. When doing `Foo& ref = *ptrFoo;`, you are making a reference to `*ptrFoo`. Only one `Foo` exists at this time. Any change you make to `ref` or `*ptrFoo` will affect the same object.
2. When you do `Foo afoo = *ptrFoo;` (which is the same as `Foo afoo = ref;`), you create *another seperate* `Foo`, which exists independently of `*ptrFoo`. It is initialised by `Foo`'s copy constructor. Note that `afoo` exists on the stack but `*ptrFoo` on the free store (heap). Any changes you make to `*ptrFoo` will not affect `afoo`, and *vice versa*. Also note that `afoo` will be destroyed and its memory freed automatically when it goes out of scope, but `*ptrFoo` must be destroyed and its memory freed explicitly by doing `delete ptrFoo;`
3. The `const` in this case means that the function accepts a reference to a `Foo` which it promises not to modify. It cannot call any methods on that `Foo` that are not marked as `const`. Also, when you call this function, no new `Foo` is created (that is, it is not passed by value).

Answer (score 2):

1) It's creating a reference to the object pointed to by ptrFoo, no new object is created.

2) The copy constructor is called and it is creating a new object of type Foo.

3) The const means that you're passing a reference to an object whose data should not be modified.

Answer (score 2):

1) It assigns the memory address of the object returned by `*(ptrFoo)`, which equivalent to `ptrFoo`.

2) The copy constructor is called.  You now have two objects, one that is allocated on the heap and pointed to by `ptrFoo` and another that is allocated on the stack and is named `afoo`.

3) The `const` means that the method `methodBar` cannot modify the object that is referenced by the `Foo&` named `instance`.  It will only be allowed to call methods on `Foo` that are also marked as `const`.